# Why does the default S3 method gets called when I pass a vector to the method and the vector S3 method is implemented?

Tags: r, generics, r-s3

I have defined the following in R:

```
plotWaterfall         <- function(x, ...) UseMethod("plotWaterfall")
plotWaterfall.default <- function(x, ...) {print("Default method does nothing")}
plotWaterfall.vector  <- function(x, ...) {print("Vector method does something")}
```

Now if I test the following example:

```
x<-c(1,2,3)
plotWaterfall(x)
```

it will print "Default method does nothing" indicating that the S3 framework matches the default method instead of the vector method. Now why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the class of your vector is `numeric`.  So you have to do this:

```
plotWaterfall.numeric  <- function(x, ...) {print("Numeric vector")}

plotWaterfall(x)
[1] "Numeric vector"
```

---

You can determine the class of an object with the `class()` function:

```
class(x)
[1] "numeric"
```

---

This behaviour is described in the help for `?UseMethod`:

> Method dispatch takes place based on the class(es) of the first
>   argument to the generic function or of the object supplied as an
>   argument to UseMethod

Comment: Thank you for you answer. The only thing that confuses me a bit then is the internal working of is.numeric and is.vector since

    > is.vector(a)
    [1] TRUE
    > is.numeric(a)
    [1] TRUE

Does that mean that vector is not a "class" in the sense as data.frame is a "class"?

Comment: Indeed, like you say, it's pretty obvious from the documentation. Thank you again.

Comment: @Dr.Mike the `is.*` functions are somewhat orthogonal to the S3 class system. It's confusing